# How to match Row and Row +1 Using apply R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, nested-loops, apply

I am attempting to replace an inefficient nested for loop that will not run on a large dataset with the apply function.

```
    unique <- cbind.data.frame(c(1,2,3))
    colnames(unique) <- "note"

    ptSeensub <- rbind.data.frame(c(1,"a"), c(1,"b"), c(2,"a"), c(2,"d"), c(3,"e"), c(3,"f"))
    colnames(ptSeenSub) <- c("PARENT_EVENT_ID", "USER_NAME")

    uniqueRow <- nrow(unique)
    ptSeenSubRow <- nrow(ptSeenSubRow)

    for (note in 1:uniqueRow)
    {
       for (row in 1:ptSeenSubRow)
       {
         if (ptSeenSub$PARENT_EVENT_ID[row] == unique$note[note])
         {
           unique$attending_name[note] <- ptSeenSub$USER_NAME[row]
           unique$attending_name[note] <- ptSeenSub$USER_NAME[row +1]
         } 
       }
     }
```

I would like the results to be similar to this dataframe:

```
results <- rbind.data.frame(c(1, "a", "b"), c(2, "a", "d"), c(3,"e", "f"))
colnames(results) <- c("note", "attending_name", "resident_name")
```

The loop will be running over millions of rows and will not finish. How can I vectorize this to finish over large data sets? Any advice is greatly apprecaited

Comment: One problem is that when using any of the `*apply` tools, the referenced function does not know *where* in the data set it is (i.e., the row), so it cannot easily get the *next* (or previous) row. One way around this may be to bring the necessary data from the next row to the current one (using `lead`, perhaps), that way you can use `apply` and not need to know about the next row.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. For instance, you define `ptSeensub` but later refer to `ptSeenSub` (note the capitalization difference). Can you clean up your post?

Comment: `apply` offers no speed advantage over nested loops especially if you need to reference by row numbers. One way to hack row numbers into `*apply` is to set `apply(X = 1:nrow(df), function(x) g(data[x,]))` as opposed to the more conventional `apply(X = df, function(x) g(df))`

Comment: the bad naming conventions are creating inconsistencies in your example.  Here `ptSeenSubRow <- nrow(ptSeenSubRow)` produces an error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to reshape data into wide format. I find that `dplyr` and `tidyr` find nice tools to accomplish this.

**define data**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
ptSeenSub <- rbind.data.frame(c(1,"a"), c(1,"b"), c(2,"a"), c(2,"d"), c(3,"e"), c(3,"f"))
```

**reshape**

```
result <- ptSeenSub %>%
  group_by(PARENT_EVENT_ID) %>%
  mutate(k = row_number()) %>%
  spread(k, USER_NAME)
```

You can then change names if you wish:

```
names(result) <- c("notes", "attending_name", "resident_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `dcast` from either `reshape2` or the devel version of `data.table` (should be fast) i.e. `v1.9.5`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(dcast(setDT(ptSeensub)[, N:= 1:.N, PARENT_EVENT_ID], 
  PARENT_EVENT_ID~N, value.var='USER_NAME'), 
        c('note', 'attending_name', 'resident_name'))[]
#   note attending_name resident_name
#1:    1              a             b
#2:    2              a             d
#3:    3              e             f
```

If there are only two observations per each 'PARENT_EVENT_ID'

```
 setDT(ptSeensub)[,.(attending_name=USER_NAME[1L], 
       resident_name=USER_NAME[2L]) , .(note=PARENT_EVENT_ID)]
 #   note attending_name resident_name
 #1:    1              a             b
 #2:    2              a             d
 #3:    3              e             f
```